# How do I iterate over a class object that is declared as an ArrayList in another class?

Tags: java, class, arraylist

So I have 2 classes: `ClassRoom` and `Student`.

In ClassRoom, I create an Arraylist using a Student type:

```java
public class ClassRoom{
    int classID;
    String className;
    ArrayList<Student> studList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ClassRoom(int classID, String className){
        this.classID = classID;
        this.className = className;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return ("Class ID: " + classID + " Class name: " + className + " Students list: " + studList);
    }
```

I also have 2 functions. One adds a student to the list and the other sends a message to each student's phone number. This is where I'm kinda stuck.

```java
    public void addStudent(int studID, String studName, int studPhoneNum){
        Student stud = new Student(studName, studID, studPhoneNum);
        studList.add(stud);
        System.out.println(studList);
    }

    public void sendMessage(int studPhoneNum){
        for (Student phone : studList[studPhoneNum]) {
            System.out.println("Sending message to: " + phone);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to understand how to iterate over the value `studPhoneNum` that is in the `studList` arraylist.

I get this error when I'm trying to do what I pasted here: `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Student>`

I'd love to know how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: `studList[studPhoneNum]` would be valid if studList was an array (but it's not), and if studPhoneNum was an index in that array (but it's not). You want (I gess) to iterate over the list. For each element, test if it has the phone number passed as argument. And if it does, print something. I'm sure your Java book has a section about the syntax of for loops. Read it again.

Comment: Off topic but shouldn’t the `sendMessage` method take a message as an argument?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it's for the sake of learning, but generally you'd be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple.
An `ArrayList` is not an array.
To access an item in an `ArrayList`, use `[your_array_list].get([your_index])`

So to iterate over an ArrayList you can use

```
for(Student student: studList)
{
  System.out.println("Sending message to: " + student);
}
```

or

```
for(int i=0; i < studList.size(); ++i)
{
  System.out.println("Sending message to: " + studList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Running it now yields no issues but still doesn't output the sysout I added there for some reason.

Comment: Well, @DanielBeilin, studList is empty, isn't it? So it iterates 0 times, because 0 < studList.size() is false from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Streams to optimize your coding:

```
public void sendMessage(int studPhoneNum){
  Student student = studList.stream().filter(student-> student.studPhoneNum == studPhoneNum).findFirst().get();
  System.out.println("Sending message to: " + student.studName + " at " + student.studPhoneNum);
}
```

You can see the entire thing in practice here: https://repl.it/@randycasburn/Stream-Filter?language=java10&folderId=